# I am new to node js and I am not able to create my server please help me... please explain my errors

Tags: node.js, express

Please help me in creating this express server

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const log = console.log;
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.use(express.static('static'))
app.get('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')))
app.use('/about', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'about.html')))
app.use('/contact', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'contact.html')))
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + port);
```

Comment: first, you tell us what happens when you run the code and describe any errors that you see

Comment: node index.js in your terminal , better to use nodemon .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with `express.static()` is not being used correctly.  You pass `express.static()` a directory name, not a filename.  It then takes the path from the URL and looks for that path in the directory you passed to it.  If it doesn't find a direct match, it also tries a set of default file extensions such as `.html`.  So, all your `express.static()` lines are wrong.

And, to fix that, you need to move your `about.html` and other static HTML files outside of the same directory as your code.  Those public HTML files need to be in their own directory.

So, let's say that you move them to a sub-directory named `public` below `__dirname`.

That would lead to this:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// this will serve any matching file it finds in the 'public' sub-directory
// It will match / to index.html
// It will also match /about to about.html
//    and /contact to contact.html
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

Note, you do NOT want to point `express.static()` at your `__dirname` directory because then that would allow an attacker to get access to your server code and/or security credentials.  But, if you move the public files to a sub-directory and point `express.static()` only at that sub-directory, then there is no risk of serving anything except the files you explicitly put in the `public` sub-directory which can be completely safe.

Comment: i want to serve my index.html on **/**. how can i do that???

Comment: @DamanpreetSingh - `express.static()` already serves `index.html` for `/`.    Please see that described in [the doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static).  Make sure and see my lastest edits to my  answer.

Comment: @DamanpreetSingh - If this worked for you, you can indicate that to the community here on stackoverflow by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.